Epic Emr hyperdrive configuration
I am working as back-end developer in healthcare organization; we are integrating Epic EMR APIs and we need to check patient updated details in epic hyperdrive application.
I have installed but don't have any idea about hyperdrive integration setup, do you guys anyone familiar with this one. Please assist me.
